# Garageband on 10.4.11: which version and where to find it?

Tags: garageband

I'd love to install garageband on an old mac mini...
Which version will it run on 10.4.11?
Can I download it from apple site or any other source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Garageband as included with iLife '08 will work fine with Tiger but you'll need to complete the free online upgrades to 10.4 to bring it up to date.